# How can I display multiple minimum values

Tags: python

So I have two arrays one is names the second is numbers. I'm searching for the lowest value but the lowest value appears twice. I need both of these to be displayed but right now only the first appearance is being displayed. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
def least(array):
    minimum = int(array[0])
    for I in range(0, len(array)):
        if minimum > int(array[I]):
            minimum = int(array[I])
            position = i
    print(name[position] minimum)
```

Comment: Python is case-sensitive and by convention uses lower case for variables, so replace `I` with `i`. Add the missing comma between the arguments and the closing parenthesis to the `print`. If you need to print all lowest numbers' indices, you need 2 loops: first to find the lowest, then you run through the list again and print the indices. Or you collect the indices in another array and print that.

Comment: hello the above you mentioned were just typos on my part as I never copy and pasted it from my program I'm going to give your suggestions a try thank you

Comment: Please make sure your code works as described (or malfunctions as described) when posting it here. Test the exact version you show here to make sure it's a [MRE].

Answer (score 1):

`position` needs to be a *list* of positions. Append to it when you find another minimum, restart the list when you find a new minimum. (Also, return the list of minimums; let the caller print it or do whatever it needs with the list.)

```
def least(array):
    minimum = int(array[0])
    position = []
    for i, v in enumerate(array):
        if int(v) == minimum:
           position.append(i)
        elif int(v) < minimum:
           position = [i]
           minimum = int(v)
    return [name[i] for i in position]
```

Comment: thank you so much I'm going to use this code and hopefully it works

Comment: How would you write the print statement here as I need it to say ("The smallest was", name1, "with", minimum) but repeat that for both the minimums

Comment: Just return `position` (and optionally the value at the position). How to construct the string isn't that difficult; I encourage you to try it yourself before asking a separate question on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve this problem is to use min() to fetch the current minimum. Then, you can iterate through your array and print your corresponding values. Hope, the code below will be helpful. Note, that it exists functions already implemented that can gives you occurrences of a value in an array.

```
def least(array, name):
    minimum = int(min(array))
    for i in range(0, len(array)):
        if int(array[i])==minimum:
            print(name[i])
```

Comment: Thank you for this but it's part of my course and the assignment is to find an alternative way rather than using min()